# Is there a way to run "planner" in kubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, kubuntu

I have quite an extensive project planned with [planner](http://live.gnome.org/Planner) but switched my desktop to kubuntu to get away from the unity desktop of ubuntu.

Issuing the command `sudo apt-get -s install planner` gives the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  planner
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst planner (0.14.5-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:11.10/oneiric [i386])
Conf planner (0.14.5-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:11.10/oneiric [i386])
```

I have the following questions:

- Is there a way to make planner work in kubuntu? or
- is there an alternative project planing software in kubuntu?
- What is the reason, why it does not run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mix the GTK (Gnome) and the Qt (KDE) based applications. With the KDE/Kubuntu desktop the Gnome applications will install the needed GTK libraries.

Here with the Kubuntu 11.10 (simulation):

```
:~$ sudo apt-get -s install planner
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> The following extra packages will be installed:
>
> > gconf2 gconf2-common libart-2.0-2 libgconf2-4 libglade2-0
> >     libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
> >     libgtk-3-common librarian0 rarian-compat scrollkeeper
>
> Suggested packages:
>
> > gconf-defaults-service librsvg2-common gvfs
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> > gconf2 gconf2-common libart-2.0-2
> >     libgconf2-4 libglade2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common
> >     libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin   libgtk-3-common librarian0 planner
> >     rarian-compat scrollkeeper

**--- EDIT ----**

Well - that was a simulation ; )

```
man apt-get

s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
     No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually 
     change the system.
```

**Example**

Installing with the command

```
sudo apt-get install planner
```

Trying to start the Planner

K > Applications > Office > Project Management

There seems to be problems. Starting from the konsole the planner is giving an error message:

```
The program 'planner' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 764 error_code 10 request_code 152 minor_code 1)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Try#1

Turning the Desktop effects off (Alt+Shift+F12). System Settings > Desktop Effects.

A bit better. The Planner is starting but the planner window is blank.

Try#2

Turning the Desktop effects on and turning the GTK widget style to the Raleigh. System Settings > Application Appearance > GTK+ Appearance.

Now the Planner is starting and the planner window is readable.

[image]

**--- EDIT #2----**

The KDE project planner app is the KPlato: http://www.kde.org/applications/office/kplato/. I can't say what it's status is (good/bad). Package is kplato.

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get -s install planner` does not install the extra packages on my machine (see edit of question...)

Comment: Try#2 did the trick. I really appreciate you answer! Only remaining open question is then "What is the reason, why it does not run?".